# Using variables to traverse an object in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have a variables `$env` that I'd like to use when traversing a powershell object: `myObject.$env.connectionstring`

This is not working, what I want is for Powershell to evaluate it like: `myObject.Production.connectionstring` ... instead I'm getting an empty string / null object.

Can I accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to specify `$myObject` rather than `myObject`. This code snippet produces the results I think you are looking for...

```
$obj = Get-Item C:\Windows
$prop = "Name"

# prints Windows
Write-Host $obj.$prop

# prints 7
Write-Host $obj.$prop.Length
```

Comment: Good call on the missing `$` on myObject. I looked right past that.

Answer (score 0):

This should just work.  It does for me on PowerShell V3 e.g.:

```
PS> $d = Get-Date
PS> $time = 'TimeOfDay'
PS> $d.$time.ticks
809485347258
```